# Iterate over pandas series

Tags: python, pandas, series

I want to travel round the series index

```
In [44]: type(ed1)
Out[44]: pandas.core.series.Series

In [43]: for _, row  in ed1.iterrows():
...:     print(row.name)
```

and I get this error:

```
  AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'iterrows'
```

Does series has any methods like iterrows?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

#### pandas >= 1.5

`Series` objects define an [**`items`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.5/reference/api/pandas.Series.items.html#pandas.Series.items) method (the data is returned as a iterator of index-value pairs.

```
for _, val in ed1.items():
    ...
```

On older versions of pandas (< 1.5), this used to be `iteritems`.

Alternatively, you can iterate over a list by calling [**`tolist`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.tolist.html),

```
for val in ed1.tolist():
    ...
```

Word of advice, iterating over pandas objects is generally discouraged. Wherever possible, seek to vectorize. To that end, I recommend taking a look at my answer to [How to iterate over rows in a DataFrame in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16476924/how-to-iterate-over-rows-in-a-dataframe-in-pandas/55557758#55557758) which discusses better alternatives to iteration.

Comment: `Series.iteritems()` has been renamed `Series.items()`